# Why was this question reopened?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, duplicate-questions

This question was posed by enderland:

[Wasn't Rey cold on Starkiller base? Shouldn't this have impacted her somehow?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115200/wasnt-rey-cold-on-starkiller-base-shouldnt-this-have-impacted-her-somehow)

And it was promptly closed (by myself) as a dupe of this one:

[Why does Rey wear the same outfit in different environments?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115000/why-does-rey-wear-the-same-outfit-in-different-environments)

Since then, it seems to have been [reopened](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/115200/timeline) (by users ibid, enderland, Wad Cheber, Null and alexwlchan) which confused me somewhat since my answer to the dupe question specifically deals with the question of whether Rey was cold on the Starkiller base (Yes, she was) and whether it impacted on her (yes, she briefly wore a jacket).

**Given that [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/115064/20774) to the first question specifically answers the second question, why was it reopened?**

Comment: I'm guessing it's because, until you pointed this out explicitly, I would never have noticed the answers to the latter answer the former question. The part that makes it a dupe simply isn't prominent enough. In fact, your copy-pasted answer on the first question could probably use some editing to focus on what that question is asking (e.g., a picture of Rey wearing Finn's jacket instead of a picture of what Rey wears at the end of the movie).

Comment: @Ixrec - Ah, but that's why I also posted [a comment](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115200/wasnt-rey-cold-on-starkiller-base-shouldnt-this-have-impacted-her-somehow#comment279434_115200) highlighting that my answer matched the other question; *"Specifically, my answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/115064/20774) answers this question. Yes, she thinks it's cold and then she just sucks it up and gets on with her mission"*

Comment: I just voted to leave open. If your answer to the older question had been the highest-voted one, I probably would have VTCed. But is it reasonable to expect people to scroll through **all** answers to an older question in order to find the little scrap that answers a newer one?

Comment: @randal'thor - It's the second highest voted. And there's a comment highlighting precisely which answer was the dupey one.

Comment: Similar example: [Do we know Snoke predates the Empire?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113091/do-we-know-snoke-predates-the-empire), dupehammered by DVK because his answer to [Is there evidence to suggest Supreme Leader Snoke is Darth Plagueis?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110876/is-there-evidence-to-suggest-that-supreme-leader-snoke-is-darth-plagueis) contains the relevant information way down at the bottom - then reopenhammered also by DVK after he regretted his hasty decision.

Comment: @randal'thor - invalid example, sorry. I didn't MEAN to dupehammer that one, it accidentally happended when I tried to **flag** it without voting. That seems like a SE bug/poor-feature to me, so I reopened to undo the unintended effects.

Comment: @randal'thor - Having said that, [it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113091/do-we-know-snoke-predates-the-empire) probably should be closed as a dupe. I just don't want to do it because certain people in chat will start yelling bad things about me again.

Comment: @DVK I wasn't trying to draw any comparison with *your behaviour* on that question, just the objective dupiness/undupiness of the posts, which seems to be a similar issue to the ones Richard is talking about.

Comment: @randal'thor  - ah, gotcha. Well, I wash my hands off either one.

Comment: I'm guessing that the former is targetted specifically about the "cold", not her wardrobe in general. Having said that, it doesn't warrant it's own separate question. [@Thaddeus has now closed the question as dupe and requested that it does not get opened again](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115200/wasnt-rey-cold-on-starkiller-base-shouldnt-this-have-impacted-her-somehow?lq=1#comment279709_115200).

Comment: @DVK On a side topic, that's not a bug/poor-feature, though. That's perfectly intended. If you want to close-vote something, then do so. A flag is not a "lightweight close vote". You can close things and thus of course should do so and stand in for it when you intend for something to get closed.

Comment: @TARS - that feature was made before binding dupehammers.

Comment: Related discussion: [When I flag as dupe, can the system put the link to the answer and not the question?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4708/21267)

Answer (score 2):

### The question has now been closed and merged.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

<sub>(Posting this answer since I found the question on the Unanswered Questions tab just now.)</sub>